# on scrolling image position changing

Tags: css, html

```css
.page-children {
    position: relative;
}
.page-children .page-child {
    background: #333333;
    height: 497px;
    position: relative;
}
.page-children .page-child .project-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlay.black-thirty {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.table-wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.page-children .page-child .project-wrap .project {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.cell-wrap {
    padding: 0;
}
.cell-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.page-children .page-child .project-wrap .project .section-title {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
page-children .page-child .project-wrap .project .divider {
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-children">
  <!-- <div class="more-bar reg">Learn more about the Products we serve:</div> -->
   <div class="page-child">
    
    <div class="project-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://annlouise.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Palm-fruit-oil-640x400.jpg); ">
     <div class="overlay black-thirty">
      <div class="table-wrap">
       <div class="cell-wrap project">
        <div class="section-title">Palm Tree</div>
        <div class="divider teal"></div>
        <!-- <div class="section-label">one liner content here...</div> -->
        <a href="fatty_acid/index.html" class="btn white-to-red">
         Learn More
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="page-child">
    
    <div class="project-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Peach-Palm-Fruit.jpg); ">
     <div class="overlay black-thirty">
      <div class="table-wrap">
       <div class="cell-wrap project">
        <div class="section-title">Palm Tree</div>
        <div class="divider teal"></div>
        <!-- <div class="section-label">one liner content here...</div> -->
        <a href="fatty_acid/index.html" class="btn white-to-red">
         Learn More
        </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

this is my div, working perfectly on desktop screens, but not working properly in mobile devices. The problem on mobile screen is when am scrolling the page the image position changing.

Answer (score 0):

Common issue related to

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

It's disabled on mobile browsers.

You'll need some javascript to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for replaying, can you suggest me javascripts lines ?. If i give background-attachment : fixed ! important; , than also it will be disabled  ?